# How can I display the ID3 version of a mp3 in VLC?

Tags: vlc-media-player, id3

I would like to display the [ID3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) version of an mp3 in VLC. Is that possible?

I use VLC 2.1.3 on Win7.

Comment: Do you mean you wish to display the metadata (song title, artist name) from the ID3 tags? That should happen by default. What behavior are you seeing? Which version of VLC are you using and on what platform?

Comment: Just the ID3 version (e.g. [id3v2.4.0](http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-structure))